# How to select dvorak layout in Solaris 10 Java Desktop

Tags: keyboard, solaris, x11, dvorak

I am learning to use the Dvorak keyboad layout, but I am not good enough to enter passwords yet, so I need to be able to switch back to qwerty occasionally.  In KDE this works very well, Windows fudges this in a way I can live with for the little time I spend on it, but I  can't change my work box which runs Solaris 10 Java desktop. It doesn't seem to have the 'setxkbmap' command.

I could change the X11.conf file but (*see 2nd sentence*)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am good enough to type passwords in Dvorak mode, I have just changed Xorg.conf ! 
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get setxkbmap working: http://bugs.opensolaris.org/view_bug.do?bug_id=6676221

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately that's 'opensolaris' not Solaris 10. They will merge the two eventually, but that doesn't help me now.

Answer (score 0):

setxkbmap was added to Solaris Express and OpenSolaris (i.e. Solaris versions newer than Solaris 10), but has not yet been backported to Solaris 10.

On Solaris 10, you can try using xkbcomp directly to modify the XKB layouts, but you may find it's simpler to use the classic xmodmap method of setting the dvorak layout.  Some examples showing how to do this are at:

- [Dvorak in X-Windows](http://www.strout.net/info/dvorak/xwinsetup.html)
- [Introducing the Dvorak Keyboard - xmodmap keymaps](http://www.mwbrooks.com/dvorak/unix.html#xmod)